# Faster way to use datatable and nested models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatable

I am trying to use the `get_raw_records` feature within Datatables by accessing records that belong to a nested attribute. The problem is that, every time I use the search functionality, `get_raw_records` is called again and it takes a really long time because of the amount of records it's going through.

Here's an example of what my situation looks like:

```
# models/book.rb
class Book < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to organization
   has_many :chapters
end
```

.

```
# models/chapter.rb
class Chapter < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :chapter
   has_many :sections
end
```

.

```
# models/section.rb
class Section < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :chapter
   has_many :paragraphs
end
```

.

```
# models/paragraph.rb
class Paragraph < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :section
end
```

This is exactly the hierarchy that my code has with the exception of books, etc. However, in my datatable, I'm trying to get all of the paragraphs that belong to Book. This is how it currently looks:

```
# datatables/book_datatable.rb
...
def get_raw_records
  book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
  paragraph_ids = Book.paragraphs.pluck(:id)
  Paragraph.where(id: paragraph_ids)
end
```

And here's how my `Book` model look:

```
# models/book.rb
class Book < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :chapters, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :sections, through: :chapters
    has_many :paragraphs, through: sections
end
```

I feel like this is an extremely complicated nested approach that can be done a lot easier. Besides, having to call `get_raw_records` every time I type in a letter in the datatable results in long delays.

Is there a better way that I can optimize this so that I can accomplish my goal by using nested models in my datatable without it taking so long?

Comment: Why not just call `Book.find(params[:book_id]).paragraphs` in your `get_raw_records` method?

Comment: What @MartinZinovsky said or if you just want the paragraphs without looking up the book first then `Paragraph.where(book_id: params[:book_id].to_i)`; however I am not certain your post clearly explains the situation. What are you actually searching for? If this is a full text search on a book then I would recommend looking into libraries that will index this for you such as [`thinking-sphinx`](https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/v4/)

Comment: Thanks @MartinZinovsky that actually solved my issue. Easy enough!

Comment: Thanks as well @thinking-sphinx. I'm looking for Paragraphs, and they don't belong directly to book so I don't think I'd be able to use that.

Comment: @LewlSauce you can speed things up by caching query results in something like redis. Check out [`this rails guide`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching). Just make sure you invalidate cache correctly on creates/updates

Comment: Thanks @MartinZinovsky. Much appreciated!